# How to increase axis multiplier font size in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I've been trying to increase the multiplier font size in my matplotlib figure but haven't found any information on how to do this. I'd like to increase the font size of the `1e7` and `1e8` labels on my plot.

I've tried:

```
plt.rc('font', size=16)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 16)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 16)
```

[Here is the plot I'd like to alter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbIY4.png)